# Парсинг JSON с помощью NSJSONSerialization

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, парсер

Нужно распарсить список городов вот из [этого файла](http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/city.list.json.gz).
Пытался делать через JSONSerializer, но получаю ошибку: "error  NSError *   domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840"

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"citylist" ofType:@"json"];
NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSError *error;
NSData *objectData = [myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Пришел к выводу, что пробела в сериализации.
Подскажите как заставить парситься JSON или как разбить строку на дикшинари. Премного благодарен за внимание.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте записать в таком виде:

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];